# Recovering files from laptop stuck at BIOS menu

Tags: boot, data-recovery, bios

I have a Razer Blade laptop that I’ve been running Ubuntu 18 on for the last two years. For the last two weeks it had started shutting off/going to a low-level black and white screen with messages I can’t understand - `error reading something at /dev/blah/something` or the like. My solution was just to power off with the power button then turn on again. These shutdowns got progressively more frequent until yesterday when I couldn’t even get past the BIOS screen. I have a flash drive that I’m planning to boot off of after wiping the drive but would like to get a few files off the computer before (I’m assuming if possible would have to be from some low-level shell).

I also get a black menu screen with the Razer screen and options to go to a Boot Menu, a BIOS setup, and a Recovery Menu. Holding down the respective F* keys for these options just brings me to the BIOS menu. Additionally disabling Fast Boot and resetting also brings me back to BIOS menu.

Any tips/ideas?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I would suggest either to use a live session and boot from that or to take out the hard disc and connect it to another system to see if you can mount it and extract data from it. 2nd note: make sure you use EFI when the disk is setup to use EFI. and no fast boot.

Comment: Thanks. So with the fast boot option I could boot from a flash drive and access the hard drive of the comp?